# Saving generated images on IIS virtual directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-7, virtual-directory

I need to create web API that generate some images and return their paths.

I create the path to save using:

```
var resultPath = "Images/" + obiektId.ToString() + ".png";
var fullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/" + resultPath);
```

and return `resultPath`.

The problem is, that the virtual directory where I keep my site is `C:\\sites\siteA` and `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/" + resultPath)` returns `C:\\inetpub\wwwroot\Images\123456.png`. Then it is impossible for me to load the image from `10.0.0.106/siteA/Images/123456.png`.

How can I save my image in my base virtual directory instead of saving it in wwwroot directory?

Comment: try this `var fullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + resultPath);`

Comment: @PranavPatel It works. Thank You :)

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string resultPath = obiektId.ToString() + ".png";
string fullPath  = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images"+ resultPath );
```